# Escape character for text ";" in csv

Tags: csv, escaping, delimiter

I have a script that calls an api and returns a text that I save in a csv.
The api sometimes returns a text containing ";".
This ";" is the delimiter of the csv so it generates new columns in the file.
How can I do to "escape" the semicolon and not generate new columns when the text has ";"?

Thanks!

Comment: You could replace ";" with "$semi_colon$" in your text before export and then replace "$semi_colon$" with ";" after import.

Comment: I have worked a lot with CSV, and there isn't really any good "covers all" method. Analyze your output and choose a delimiter that you know fairly certainly is not in the text. It can be an accented character, a `§` etc.  Fixed-width columns (width is determined by longest column entry) is another way to cover every ascii character. Or go by tab-delimited if you don't need tabs in your output.  Escaping `;` is a wormhole that leads to escaping hell. You could end up with `\\\\\\\\;` type results.